# Вывод последних 10 записей как ASC mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Делаю чат как в ВК. Нужно вывести последние записи ( Сообщения ) в виде ASC.
Допустим в базе записи от 1 до 30, мне нужно вывести записи в рамках 20-30, то есть через DESC LIMIT 10. Но как после и при выводе сделать их в виде ASС? Не 30, 29, 28...20 а 20,21,22...30?

Comment: Думаю как то через цикл при выводе? Засунуть в массив и присвоить идентификаторы в обратном порядке?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делаем выборку последних 10, после чего во внешнем запросе пересортировываем в другом порядке:

```
select * from (
  select * from table
   order by id desc limit 10
) A
 order by id
```

Comment: Хм, быстро решили задачу) Браво)